# Create a native app using other than Java or Objective C

Tags: java, android, ios, erlang, whatsapp

My question is based on what I read about Whatsapp. I read that it is built using Erlang. I also read that it is a native app. But I know that native apps can be created using Java/Kotlin for Android and Objective C/Swift for IOS. So I would like to know how was Whatsapp created as a native app using Erlang. Also, is it possible to use other programming languages to create native apps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The backend is in Erlang; I don't believe the mobile apps are.

Comment: if you want somewhat near to native try searching react native or flutter by google

Comment: Native apps generally means apps that are installed on and execute on the device, as opposed to web apps that are delivered in a web browser.  Web apps may execute some code locally through JavaScript, but it is inside the web browser, not running directly under the OS.  You can produce "native" apps in any number of languages, all that is needed is the ability to compile a binary that can run under the os. E.g. xamarin lets you use c# to produce native apps

Comment: forgot to mention erlang is used for backend not fir the clients application.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp's *back end* is written in Erlang, among other things. This is the server-side code that handles messaging. The app on mobile devices is written in Java/Kotlin and Objective-C/Swift. I'm not sure exactly which they use.

There are other frameworks that allow you to create native apps, like [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)(which uses the Angular web framework), or [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)(which uses React). These frameworks generate the native code for you from web apps you write using JavaScript, HTML, CSS, etc.